# serious problems with wamp server on my new laptop

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I have a new laptop; windows 8.1 64bit. Im using wampserver with apache 2.4.9 and php 5.5.12. My laptop has Microsoft Visual C ++ 2012 installed.

Im trying to install a Drupal website.Before installation i created a database. I copy and rename the settings.php file and I install Drupal. So far never a problem.

Then when i start installing modules there comes a moment when i get the following error message

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error -1 from storage engine: TRUNCATE {cache_rules} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 167 of C:\wamp\www\xxx\includes\cache.inc).
```

The error is followed by the following error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'alleserin.cache_rules' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM {cache_rules} WHERE (expire <> :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (expire < :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1441699681 ) in cache_clear_all() (line 167 of C:\wamp\www\xxxx\includes\cache.inc).
```

If i understand correct.. My Drupal installations doesnt see my database anymore?

Im having this problem for days now. My old laptop crashed. I cant see which versions of wampserver i had there. I used the same Drupal 7.39 and all modules i used were up to date. I had no problems there.

I have done many new installs. Removed wampserver and databases. Everytime the error occurs again randomly and i cant do anything anymore with the site. I have tried to clear caches. Changed the engine from InnoDB to myIsam. I have tried to install Drupal using XAMMP. It happens everytime.
It seems to be a problems with the settings in my wampserver. Not Drupal

Im really running out of ideas. Something must be wrong with my new laptop. I must be missing some package to make Drupal function normal.

Anybody having any ideas?

Comment: Are you installing WAMP into your root C:/ directory?

Comment: Lets start at the beginning, what colour is your wampmanager icon in the system tray?

Comment: Hi Riggy.. It is green. It is running and for apache i have turned on alias_module, rewrite_module and vhost_alias_module. For php i have these extensions enabled php_curl php_gd2 php_mysqli. I can download Drupal and install the first modules but then everytime i get the errors as described above

Answer (score 0):

i think something goes wrong during your installation. Do you know drush ? It's recommanded to use drush to install Drupal. 
Otherwise, yo can go on phpmyadmin and in your databases select all tables who begins by "cache" and TRUNCATE it, in same time check if table explicited in message error exist. 
Check integrity of settings.php information (database name, user, password, etc..)

Comment: I dont use Drush. Can go try to do that. I have already selected all tables in the database that begin with cache and emptied it. No result.

Comment: Install drush and drush registry rebuild 
http://www.drush.org/en/master/install/ 
And see drush documentation , it's very helpful when you work on drupal 7